# onclick or inline script isn't working in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclick, firefox-addon-webextensions

This seems to be the easiest thing to do, but it's just not working. In a normal browser the .html and .js files works perfectly, but in the Chrome/Firefox extension the `onClick` function is not performing what it's supposed to do.

.js file:

```js
function hellYeah(text) {
  document.getElementById("text-holder").innerHTML = text;
}
```

.html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Getting Started Extension's Popup
    </title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="text-holder">
      ha
    </div>
    <br />
    <a onClick=hellYeah("xxx")>
      hyhy
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

So basically once the user clicks "hyhy", "ha" should change into "xxx". And again - it works perfectly in the browser but does not work in the extension. Do you know why? Just in case I'm attaching the manifest.json below as well.

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Chrome Extensions don't allow you to have inline JavaScript ([documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)).
The same goes for Firefox WebExtensions ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Inline_JavaScript)).

You are going to have to do something similar to this:

Assign an ID to the link (`<a onClick=hellYeah("xxx")>` becomes `<a id="link">`), and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to bind the event. Put the following in your `popup.js` file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        hellYeah('xxx');
    });
});
```

`popup.js` should be loaded as a separate script file:

```html
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got something like this: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:"."

Comment: Javascript cannot be in your HTML file for extensions. You have to load all javascript from an external source. Something like `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`

Comment: @teeZee For future reference, put backticks (\`) around your code to format it in comments. `Like this.`

Comment: The markup in my popup is generated at runtime (e.g.. <a> tags with values that are not going to be predictable).  I've set the ids of my <a> tags equal to the value of the <a> tag innerhtml as such:

<a href="#" id="xxxxxx">xxxxxx</a>
<a href="#" id="abc123">abc123</a>

but I need to pass the value to javascript for processing when they are clicked...  how would I do that?  Ultimately, just to get javascript to alert the value of the href clicked would be a good start.

Comment: Note that even though you cannot do inline `onclick="handleClick()"`, you can still use `el.onclick = handleClick`.

Answer (score 50):

### Reason

This does not work, because Chrome [forbids any kind of inline code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) in extensions via Content Security Policy.

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline `<script>` blocks **and** inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

### How to detect

If this is indeed the problem, Chrome would produce the following error in the console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

To access a popup's JavaScript console (which is useful for debug in general), right-click your extension's button and select "Inspect popup" from the context menu.

More information on debugging a popup is available [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

### How to fix

One needs to remove all inline JavaScript. There is [a guide in Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

Suppose the original looks like:

```
<a onclick="handler()">Click this</a> <!-- Bad -->
```

One needs to remove the `onclick` attribute and give the element a unique id:

```
<a id="click-this">Click this</a> <!-- Fixed -->
```

And then attach the listener from a script (which must be in a `.js` file, suppose `popup.js`):

```
// Pure JS:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", handler);
});

// The handler also must go in a .js file
function handler() {
  /* ... */
}
```

Note the wrapping in a `DOMContentLoaded` event. This ensures that the element exists at the time of execution. Now add the script tag, for instance in the `<head>` of the document:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Alternative if you're using jQuery:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click-this").click(handler);
});
```

### Relaxing the policy

**Q:** The error mentions ways to allow inline code. I don't want to / can't change my code, how do I enable inline scripts?

**A:** Despite what the error says, you [**cannot** enable inline script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script):

> There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes `'unsafe-inline'` will have no effect.

**Update:** Since Chrome 46, it's possible to whitelist specific inline code blocks:

> As of Chrome 46, inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See [Hash usage for `<script>` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage) for an example.

However, I do not readily see a reason to use this, and it will not enable inline attributes like `onclick="code"`.

Comment: if I want to do it same with class name instead Id.. I tried but no luck'

Comment: Any thoughts on how one might anonymize this solution so that it could work for an angular app with generated div names? I can't create event listeners because the names of the buttons all have to be unique for each item in my ng repeat... :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and didn´t want to rewrite the code, so I wrote a function to modify the code and create the inline declarated events:

```
function compile(qSel){
    var matches = [];
    var match = null;
    var c = 0;

    var html = $(qSel).html();
    var pattern = /(<(.*?)on([a-zA-Z]+)\s*=\s*('|")(.*)('|")(.*?))(>)/mg;

    while (match = pattern.exec(html)) {
        var arr = [];
        for (i in match) {
            if (!isNaN(i)) {
                arr.push(match[i]);
            }
        }
        matches.push(arr);
    }
    var items_with_events = [];
    var compiledHtml = html;

    for ( var i in matches ){
        var item_with_event = {
            custom_id : "my_app_identifier_"+i,
            code : matches[i][5],
            on : matches[i][3],
        };
        items_with_events.push(item_with_event);
        compiledHtml = compiledHtml.replace(/(<(.*?)on([a-zA-Z]+)\s*=\s*('|")(.*)('|")(.*?))(>)/m, "<$2 custom_id='"+item_with_event.custom_id+"' $7 $8");
    }

    $(qSel).html(compiledHtml);

    for ( var i in items_with_events ){
        $("[custom_id='"+items_with_events[i].custom_id+"']").bind(items_with_events[i].on, function(){
            eval(items_with_events[i].code);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    compile('#content');
})
```

This should remove all inline events from the selected node, and recreate them with jquery instead.

Comment: this code is not executing properly please guide me in proper way

Answer (score 1):

I decide to publish my example that I used in my case. I tried to replace content in div using a script. My problem was that Chrome did not recognized / did not run that script.

In more detail What I wanted to do: To click on a link, and that link to "read" an external html file, that it will be loaded in a div section.

- I found out that by placing the script before the DIV with ID that
  was called, the script did not work.
- If the script was in another DIV, also it does not work
- The script must be coded using document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() as it was told

  ```
      <body>
      <a id=id_page href ="#loving"   onclick="load_services()"> loving   </a>

          <script>
                  // This script MUST BE under the "ID" that is calling
                  // Do not transfer it to a differ DIV than the caller "ID"
                  document.getElementById("id_page").addEventListener("click", function(){
                  document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML = '<object data="Services.html" class="loving_css_edit"; ></object>'; });
              </script>
      </body>

    <div id="mainbody" class="main_body">
          "here is loaded the external html file when the loving link will 
           be  clicked. "
    </div>
  ```

Comment: I am not sure.... if it is 100% working properly. The txt/html definition was removed.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Chrome Extensions don't allow to have inline JavaScript due to security reasons so you can try this workaround as well.

HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Getting Started Extension's Popup
            </title>
            <script src="popup.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="text-holder">ha</div><br />
            <a class="clickableBtn">
                  hyhy
            </a>
        </body>
    </html>
<!doctype html>
```

popup.js

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target ;
    if(target.matches('.clickableBtn')) {
        var clickedEle = document.activeElement.id ;
        var ele = document.getElementById(clickedEle);
        alert(ele.text);
    }
}
```

Or if you are having a Jquery file included then

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target ;
    if(target.matches('.clickableBtn')) {
        alert($(target).text());
    }
}
```