# Javascript throwing : Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm newbie in google chrome extention delveopment.
I'm trying to develop a simple extension and i keep getting the error above.

my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "set my favourties",
  "description" : "just another super awesome plugin",
  "version" : "0.1", 
    "background": {
    "page": "backround.html"
  },

   "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

   "browser_action" :{
     "popup" : "popup.html",
     "default_icon" : "icon.gif"
     },

     "permissions" : ["notifications"]
 }
```

the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "backround.js">

</script>
</head>
<body onload = "loadHandler()">

</body>
</html>
```

and the js:

```
  function loadHandler(){
  window.webkitNotifications.createNotification("icon.gif","Plugin Loaded","it was loaded").show();

   }
```

thanks in advance

Nir

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<del>If this wasn't a Chrome extension, you could add `'unsafe-inline'` to the list of acceptable places to load scripts from,</del> but you should avoid using inline event handlers at all.

Replace (in the HTML):

```
onload = "loadHandler()"
```

with (in the script):

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadHandler);
```

Comment: `unsafe-inline` doesn't work in Chrome extensions. Moving the event listener to a separate script file is the only solution.

Comment: unfortunately yes. Now we have to figure out how to manage so many dynamically attached click events.

Answer (score 7):

Correct. This is documented here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts

Comment: the link is broken