# The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have created a JavaScript variable and when I click on the button it should increment by 1, but its not happening.

Here's `manifest.json`.

```
{
  "name":"Facebook",
  "version":"1.0",
  "description":"My Facebook Profile",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"google-plus-red-128.png",
    "default_popup":"hello.html"
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var a=0;
function count()
{
  a++;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a;
  return a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">=a</p>
<button type="button" onclick="count()">Count</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the extension to show me the value of a and increment it by one each time I click on the extension or the button

[image: picture of the extension]

Comment: You're missing the opening `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito that too. (with my answer)

Comment: @Neal add it to your answer, so that it's more visible :)

Comment: @timothyonggowasito still having the same issue when i click on the extension it shows me =a and the count button and when i click on the count button it stays the same

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito Fancy time: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ck5Yz/7/ ^_^

Comment: Please edit your question to show the whole code. Is that HTML a part of your Chrome extension? If yes, move all inline JavaScript to an external file, see [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: Hi @RobW i have edited the question let me know if any changes are needed

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Your code is not working because it violates the default [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). I've created a screencast of one minute to show what's wrong:

[image: screencast]

First, I've shown how to debug the problem. Right-click on your popup button, and click on ["Inspect popup"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup). After doing that, you will see the following error message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

This explains that your code is not working, because it violates the default CSP: [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution). To solve the problem, you have to remove all inline JavaScript from your HTML file, and put it in a separate JS file.

The result is shown below:

#### `hello.html` (popup page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">=a</p>
<button type="button" id="do-count">Count</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### `popup.js`

```js
var a=0;
function count() {
    a++;
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = a;
}
document.getElementById('do-count').onclick = count;
```

Note that I've replaced `innerHTML` with `textContent`. Learn to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when you intend to change the text. In this simple example it does not matter, but in more complex applications, it might become a security issue in the form of XSS.

Comment: this worked like a charm and can you let me know how to store the number till i close the browser.

Comment: @sainath [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) is your friend.

Comment: +1 for creative graphical GIF :) You've got to teach me how to make those sometime.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's created using byzanz, I've written shell scripts to ease the use: http://askubuntu.com/a/201018/45058

Comment: Mine keeps on adding one and then quickly resetting to 0. What am I doing wrong? Note that I had to wrap my call in a `window.onload = function () {}` method.

Comment: @skaz When the popup is closed, the page is unload. If you want to save state, store the data somewhere, e.g. in `chrome.storage` or in the background page.

Comment: @RobW I am not closing the popup, just clicking the button over and over, but it resets to zero. Maybe the button click is quickly triggering the closing of the popup?

Comment: popup.js

`window.onload = function () {

var button = document.getElementById("do-test");
button.onclick = count();

function count() {
 var a = 0;
 var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
 return function () {
     demo.textContent = ++a;
 }
}
}`

Comment: @Robw gui.js 

`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">0</div>    


<form>
Username2: <input type='text' id="username" name='username'></input>
Password: <input type='password' id='password' />
<button id="do-test" onclick="">Login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @skaz Get rid of the `<form>`. Now, when you press the button, a form is submitted, causing the page to reload. Or add `document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e){e.preventDefault();};`

Comment: This is one of the highest quality answers I've ever seen on S/O, and I've been here 6 years

Comment: @toddmo Thanks for the compliment!

Answer (score -1):

Change your `onclick`:

```
onclick="count"
```

**Or** change your count function to something like this:

```
function count()
{

    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    return function() {
        demo.innerHTML = ++a;
    }

}
```

---

Here is a nice demo I put together:

Code (this assumes that you add `id="the_button"` to your button):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
    button.onclick = count();

    function count() {
        var a = 0;
        var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
        return function () {
            demo.innerHTML = ++a;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ck5Yz/

Comment: if i change it to count it will not recognize it as a function count() if i'm right

Comment: @sainath with increment and decrement functions: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ck5Yz/7/

Comment: still my chrome extention is only showing count now and no matter how much i click it still has only one value

Comment: I have changed the code and it works when i run it as a html file but when i load it to chrome extension and when i click on it here is the manifest
{
    "name":"Facebook",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"My Facebook Profile",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"google-plus-red-128.png",
        "default_popup":"hello.html"
    }
}

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
    button.onclick = count();

    function count() {
        var a = 0;
        var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
        return function () {
            demo.innerHTML = ++a;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<button type="button" id="the_button">Count</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: my aim is to create an extension that will give me the number of times i clicked at the extension and now i'm only getting the button in the popup