# Showing generated page in a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a unstable internet connection and would like to monitor the router log via a chrome extension. Since i am just starting with programming i decided to create a new tab browserAction calling a html page that simply contained a HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" pointing at my browser log. That way i wiggled out of the same origin policy. That since stopped working without a reason or error log entry i could start from. Could anybody give me some pointers as to how i could get this back working, improve this and or tell me how weird/wrong my approach is? :)

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Logview",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Logview Extension",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "Logview Extension"
    },
    "background": {
      "page": "background.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ]
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "redirect.html"});
        });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

redirect.html

```
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://user:pass@192.168.1.1/logview.cmd">
</head>
```

Please be gentle, its my first post here and i researched a ton of stuff before posting. The meta refresh was the only thing i could come up with that went around same origin hazards or public apis that i cannot use in the event of the router being down. All obvious errors were made out of inexperience rather than negligence. I just hit a wall with it just not doing anything anymore.

All the best,
morph

edit: changed the title to ...new tab (was ...pop-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r bitten by the beast called [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). Don't worry, you are not the first one to experience this, I see this mistake getting repeated every week.

Before jumping to the solution, I want to equip one with the tools to solve the issue, by presenting two previous answers:

- [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029)
  This is the first step in the process of debugging - seeing the error messages.
- [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled/17612988#17612988)
  This answer solves a similar problem. The only difference between the questions is that your question is about the background page, whereas the other question is about the popup..

After reading the last answer, you should understand the problem with your code, and understand that the solution looks like:

### `background.html`

```html
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

### `background.js`

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "redirect.html"});
});
```

If your [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) consists of only scripts, just use the background.scripts syntax in the manifest file. Then, you don't need `background.html` any more.

### `manifest.json` (part of it)

```
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"],
   "persistent": false
},
```

Final notes:

- I have added `"persistent":false` to your manifest file, to turn your background page into an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html). Most of the time, your extension is doing nothing, so using an event page instead of a background page saves memory.
- You can safely remove the `tabs` permission from the manifest file. It is not needed if you only want to open a new tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for that extensive answer. You have an instant fan, klicking on your username opened a whole treasure trove for me. It appears the worst wrong assumptions you have are the ones you don't know you have. No different were your final remarks. I was under the impression that "persistent": false was implied if i don't set it to true - as well as i read the documentation of for tabs wrong: "Use the chrome.tabs module to interact with the browser's tab system. You can use this module to create, modify, and rearrange tabs in the browser."

Comment: Now since that works so well, if you don't mind me asking: In the above scenario. Where would i have to look for doing things like parsing the generated router log page for say a certain entry? That probably has been done before often, but i'm not sure where to start. Most Questions are about sites that are already open in a tab or similar. Uhm and i just realize, is it good practise to ask that in a new question?

Comment: @morph Yes, for entirely different questions, you should create a new question, because it generates more exposure. And who knows, maybe it's useful to some future visitor with the same problem ;) To answer your question: Use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to read data from the page.