# JavaScript - Select span text on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code.

```
<div class="dontsplit" onmouseover="selCode('c111');">
  Face savoring delicious food <span class="notranslate" id="c111"></span>
</div>
```

I want to select the value between span tags when mouse hovers the div. The code I am using is this.

```
function selCode(objId) {
    if(document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
        range.select();
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How do I get this work?

I repeat. I need to automatically select the text between span when mouse hovers over the div. So it can be copied easily. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$(".notranslate").text()`?

Comment: He use vanilla ... no need of jQuery here

Comment: Even a jQuery method would be welcome.

Comment: Ok...then its better to remove `jQuery` tag from the question...got confused.

Comment: no no...any method that works I need.

Comment: Any example of how to do it with jQuery?

Comment: See my answer below if its of any help

Comment: Well if this code looks like vanilla ... if you need jQuery put jQuery in the whole code not just for a text selection and btw with jQuery Sandeep Nayak provided you a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working for the first mouseover but the second one inwards is giving the error `Discontiguous selection is not supported.` so clear the existing selection before doing a new selection.

```
function selCode(objId) {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/er3q1jpu/)

Comment: Thanks. This works in browser. But when trying to use it in a chrome extension, it's not working.

Comment: i figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help.

You can use jQuery `.text()` method.

You have a `span` with `notranslate` class.

So you can do somthing like this to get the text:

```
$(".notranslate").text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8r6ns88/

Comment: Thanks! It's "alerting" the text. Anyway to select the text or copy it to clipboard?

Comment: Just a demo..you can modify it accordingly to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I'm using jquery to make this task done.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dontsplit">
  Face savoring delicious food <span class="notranslate" id="c111"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  $('.dontsplit').on('mouseover','.notranslate', function(){
  console.log($(this).text()); //see result
 })
})
```