# button in popup.html not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup.html, and what I thought was pretty simple listener event.

This is my popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button id="button">Starting Now</button>

  <script>
    function blah(){
      alert("blah");
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", blah);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There's no alert when I press the button; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try some of the documentation and tutorials in w3schools.com, great website.  http://www.w3schools.com/ .  your html code need to know about  your javascript, you do not have anything in your html referencing the javascript.

Comment: wow I feel rly dumb, thanks a lot!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

Comment: @abraham Duplicate does not fit well - this is a different kind of inline code. There must be a duplicate target, but that ain't it.

Comment: @imhappi Please check edited answer - earlier on I wrote that `alert` is not allowed `coz of `CSP` but checking the guideline again it does allow `alert` . Thanks @Xan for pointing out

Comment: It's the same issue, move inline javascript to separate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is okay from normal web-page point of view but from the guidelines of Chrome Extension Development you need to check [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) which says:

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both
>   inline `<script>` blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

So, what you can do to test your code is place the script code in a separate `.js` file and then refer it in your html.

As suggested by [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) in comments about the usage of `alert()`: 
In place of `alert()` you can use simple `console.log()` if the purpose is only to test the button click or else if you really want pop-up alert like thing then create a modal dialog.

---

**Just for reference only** (*Probably OP is already aware of it though*):

Since you are using `jQuery` [check this guideline also about loading jQuery or other libraries](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading).

Comment: thanks a lot :) I wasn't aware of the chrome extension guidelines

Comment: Wrong on "CSP doesn't allow `alert()`", it does not allow `eval()`. However, having a focus-stealing alert window in a focus-sensitive popup is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @Xan well that depends upon use case

Comment: I agree with the recommendation to use `console.log()`, but the statement in your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Xan can you plz cite the statement that seemed wrong to you

Comment: I already did in my first comment. `alert()` is fine with CSP, `eval()` and friends are not. See "should write code like" section in your link, it uses `alert()` - just not explicit or implicit `eval`.

Comment: @Xan ohh my bad.. mistook the code - snippet from the guideline. Thankx for pointing out. Let me quickly edit the answer :)

Comment: Like I said, using `alert()` is _still bad_, but for other reasons: it can make your popup lose focus and close. Your recommendation is solid - though I'd add instructions to find **Inspect popup**.

Comment: @Xan yeah your point makes sense let me add that part as well