# Script tags don't work in Chrome Dev Editor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-dev-editor

I'm using the Chrome App "Chrome Dev Editor" to make an Extension, but for some reason the script tags (which are in body tags) don't seem to work. 
I have tried to take the code and put it in codepen.io (an online HTML/CSS/JS editor and it seems to work fine there.

Here is the code:

```
<div id = "thingy"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("thingy").innerHTML = "Yo";
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and sorry for my lack of knowledge on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Beside providning a codepen/jsfiddle link that can help what about trying to remove spaces from div id? so `<div id="thingy">`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [button in popup.html not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418915/button-in-popup-html-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow javascript in extensions like that. The code has to be in a separate .js file for it to work as an extension.

Just swap your code for this:

```
<script src="otherfile.js"></script>
```

Then put the javascript in otherfile.js

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't seem to work. I have tried putting the snippet you gave me into the body tags and outside them and it still doesn't want to work. (I also changed the file name since mine is "script.js" and all I have in the .js file is "document.getElementById("thingy").innerHTML = "hi";

Comment: Oh sorry, when I tested it I accidentally took out the div tags with the id in it, the tags work now. Thanks so much!