# Chrome Extension - js with parameters not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been coding chrome extension popup with js that calls with a parameter.

here is html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <p id="demo">=a</p>
    <button type="button" id="do-count1">Count1</button>
    <button type="button" id="do-count2">Count2</button>  
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

since chrome extension js must be separated

popup.js

```
var a=0;
 function count(k) {
     a = a + k;
     document.getElementById('demo').textContent = a;
}
document.getElementById('do-count1').onclick = count(2);
document.getElementById('do-count2').onclick = count(5);
```

when opening the popup window it gives 7, as those 2 functions executed automatically without clicking. further the buttons don't work.

a similar question was asked 
[The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

but my question one step advanced since i need to call js function with a parameter onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're assigning a *result of the function call*, not a function reference.

Your options are:

- use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a function wrapper that will pass the parameter:

  ```
  element1.onclick = count.bind(null, 2);
  element2.onclick = count.bind(null, 5);
  ```

  Note: `this` of the onclick function will be lost this way.
- or use a simple function wrapper:

  ```
  element1.onclick = function() { count(2) };
  element2.onclick = function() { count(5) };
  ```

  Note: `this` of the onclick function will be lost this way, to preserve it:

  ```
  element1.onclick = function() { count.call(this, 2) };
  element2.onclick = function() { count.call(this, 5) };
  ```
- use an HTML attribute:

  popup.html:

  ```
  <button type="button" id="do-count1" data-add="2">Count1</button>
  <button type="button" id="do-count2" data-add="5">Count2</button>
  ```

  popup.js:

  ```
  function count() {
      document.getElementById('demo').textContent = a = a + this.dataset.add;
  }
  element1.onclick = count;
  element2.onclick = count;
  ```