# How to fix chrome-extension inline JavaScript invocation error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm making a chrome extension however I seem to get the following error when I try to fire up an onclick() event.

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"
```

and

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

This is my manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SECURE",
  "description": "this extension offers secure communication for GMAIL     users",
  "version": "1.0",

 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "resources/icon16.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html",
 "default_title": "Click here!"


 },

 "background":{
   "scripts":["background.js"]
},

 "content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
   "js":["myscript.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
  }
  ],
"permissions": ["identity", "https://accounts.google.com/*",  "https://www.googleapis.com/*"],

"oauth2": {
   "client_id": "975410329966.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scopes": [
   "<all urls>",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
   "https://mail.google.com/",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.login",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
  ],

 "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe eval'  https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?; object-src 'self'"


}
}
```

Any help towards fixing this error would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

Answer (score 22):

By default [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), inline scripts won't be loaded and only local script can be loaded. You could relax the default policy by:

1. Inline Script. Take a look at [Official Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script), inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. See [Hash usage for  elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage) for an example.

   **But I believe a better way would extract this logic to a separate script and not use inline script.**
2. Remote Script. You could whitelist script resources `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad` by the following section in `manifest.json`

   ```
   "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
   ```

   **Also, I believe a better way could be downloading the remote `client.js` and include it as a local script.**

Please be aware as per the description of [Inline Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script), `unsafe-inline` no longer works.

> Up until Chrome 45, there was no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, s**etting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect**.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by outsourcing everything into the JavaScript file.
So instead of the onclick method in the html I have in the JS file:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = <function>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead of onclick in an external file:

```
document.getElementById("#divId").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```