# Appending or executing a script within an iframe created by Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

## Main Question

I'm building a Chrome extension that involves appending an iframe to the page. The extension makes an AJAX call in the background page to retrieve the URLs of the external CSS / JS to include and so I need to dynamically add these resources to the iframe. The iframe code is an HTML page that's included in the extension's [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) (it has a URL of chrome-extension://...)

This is what I do in the iframe:

```
window.onload = function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getResources"}, function(response) {
    // get urls of css / js files
    let { css, js } = response; // css and js are arrays of urls retrieved

    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.href = css[i];
      link.type = "text/css";
      link.rel = "stylesheet";

      head.appendChild(link);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = js[i];
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.onload = function() {
        window.alert('loaded script');
      }
      head.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
}
```

After this, I can log the stylesheets and scripts from the head so they are appended successfully. However, the callback in the script.onload is not called and I tried using getComputedStyle like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27331817/4368048) to check the CSS and that didn't work. So both the stylesheets and scripts are not actually being executed.

I'm wondering if Chrome extensions just don't allow dynamic injections into iframes.

---

## Additional Info

Here are some things I tried:

- #### Adding the URLs to the permissions

  Mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions). All the scripts I load are from sites outlined in the permissions field of the manifest.json file so CORS shouldn't be a problem.
- #### Trying hacky ways to load the script

  I tried `script.innerHTML = "console.log('success')"` and also tried `head.innerHTML = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="[URL_TO_LOAD]"></scr' + 'ipt>'`. Neither worked. I didn't try any solutions with `document.write` or `eval` just because I would never use those even if they worked for security reasons.
- #### SetTimeout

  I tried setting a timeout after loading the script in case it took a while to execute but even after 10 seconds, global variables that should've been there are still undefined.
- #### HTTPS

  Requesting scripts served over HTTPS also did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's due to Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622181/how-to-fix-chrome-extension-inline-javascript-invocation-error). However the scripts that can be dynamically injected into the iframe must be either local files or served over HTTPS.