# What does this error mean in the console of a chrome extension that I'm trying to make?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension with HTML with some JS in it, but when I open the extension, all I see is a tiny white square. When I inspected the extension, and went to console I saw this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Popup Game",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "ct.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Game"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
fill(0, 0, 0);

ellipse(200, 200, 375, 375);

fill(60, 0, 255);

triangle(200, 104, 280, 280, 120, 280);

fill(255, 255, 255);

var answer = floor(random(1, 20));


if (answer === 1) {

    text("As I see it,", 171, 200);

    text("yes", 189, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 2) {

    text("Ask again", 171, 200);

    text("later", 189, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 3) {

    text("Better not ", 171, 200);

    text("tell you now", 169, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 4) {

    text("Cannot", 180, 200);

    text("predict now", 172, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 5) {

    text("Concentrate", 169, 200);

    text("and ask again", 165, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 6) {

    text("Don't count", 171, 200);

    text("on it", 189, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 7) {

    text("It is", 191, 200);

    text("certain", 183, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 8) {

    text("It is", 193, 200);

    text("decidedly so", 169, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 9) {

    text("Most", 187, 200);

    text("likely", 186, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 10) {

    text("My reply is", 171, 200);

    text("no", 193, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 11) {

    text("My sources", 171, 200);

    text("say no", 184, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 12) {

    text("Outlook", 178, 200);

    text("not so good", 171, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 13) {

    text("Outlook", 180, 200);

    text("good", 185, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 14) {

    text("Reply hazy,", 170, 200);

    text("try again", 178, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 15) {

    text("Signs point", 170, 200);

    text("to yes", 184, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 16) {

    text("Very", 187, 200);

    text("doubtful", 180, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 17) {

    text("Without", 180, 200);

    text("a doubt", 181, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 18) {

    text("Yes", 189, 229); 

}

else if (answer === 19) {

    text("Yes - definitely", 164, 229); 

}

else {

    text("You may", 175, 200);

    text("rely on it", 177, 229); 

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for a day and nothing seems to be working. It would be great if someone could please help.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-c

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622181/how-to-fix-chrome-extension-inline-javascript-invocation-error