# Trying to test connection between my google chrome extension and my server

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm in the process of developing an app and at the moment I'm just running through all the basics and testing different aspects of what Chrome extensions can do.
I want to test that I can connect my extension to my own webserver (the aim is to eventually collect data and send it to a database).
I followed some instructions on AJAX and put this code into a simple popup extension I made. I however ran into security issues :
"Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."
I have read through the instructions that Google have about this but I'm not sure how I should correct my code.

This is what I have in popup.html:

```
<div id="demo">
        <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
        <button type="button" id="click-this" ()">Change Content</button>
      </div>
```

And this is what I have in background.js

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "my url", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

And in popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

I have my url in the permission section of manifest.json.

As I said I'm new to this so any advice or criticism is welcome!

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `handler` definition? You have to show it as well as your manifest

Comment: I'm not sure what handler definition is?

Comment: If `handler` is undefined, you get an error. Otherwise it should be defined somewhere in your code

Comment: `id="click-this" ()"` is an invalid markup. Did you mess it up here in the question? Looks like you had an inline click handler there in which case this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457), see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17601615) and just in case, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982).