# Executing inline script for a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed an extension which contains a dynamic form with single input and a '+' button. I have written inline javascript html on click event but the content security policy keeps on refusing the inline event handler to work. Where do I need to modify the CSP so that my inline script gets executed ? 
The ways I tried are replacing unsafe-eval with unsafe-inline and the other way is removing content_security_policy in manifest.json. Even i tried changing manifest_version to 1 but none of them worked.

Comment: No need to modify CSP. Simply use a separate js file as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612988).

Comment: through the script im trying to add one more input and button where the button is having the inline onclick event. This is getting refused by csp.

Comment: " <input type='text' id='item" + id + "'>" +
            " <input type='submit' id='AndButton' value='AND' onclick='AndFunction(" + id2 + ")'>" +

Comment: As shown in the answers I've linked, instead of onclick and inline code, use a separate js file.