# onClick with Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclick

So I'm pretty new when it comes to java script and creating chrome extensions. So what I'm trying to do is to take two values which the user has inputted, add them together and display after the user has clicked calculate. However I can't seem to get it to work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            First Value<input type="text" id="ValueA"/><br>
            Second Value<input type="text" id="ValueB"/><br>

            Invested Cost<input type="text" id="result"/><br>
            <button id="Calc;">Calculate</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My java script:

```
document.getElementById("Calc").addEventListener("click", Sum);

function Calc()
        {
            var A = document.getElementById('ValueA').value;
            var B = document.getElementById('ValueB').value;
            var C = A+B;
            document.getElementById('result').value = C;
        }
```

and finally my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Simple Calculator",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description":  "Simple Calculator",

    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }

}
```

Comment: Your button id says `Calc;` with a semicolon at the end. Is this on purpose?

Comment: `Sum` function undefined and wrong id name

Comment: See answers to the question [The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612988/6384980)

Comment: Thanks Julian and prasanth didn't notice the semicolon there and the incorrect function name.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Calc()` function in event listener. Right now, you are invoking `Sum`

Also, as @Julian said in the comment, you need to remove `;` from button id

Comment: So I've made the changes but now all I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, If possible could you tell me what I've done wrong and perhaps clarify what this error means?

Comment: If you have error `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`, it means that `document.getElementById("Calc")` returns null. Most common mistake is a typo. Check out if button has id `Calc` (this is case sensitive). Button should be like this `<button id="Calc">Calculate</button>`. There's a typo in your code above - `<button id="Calc;">` is not the same as `<button id="Calc">`

Comment: Thank you for the help explanation and the help. All working now :)

Comment: You are welcome :-) btw. You can mark the question as answered ;-)