# Google Chrome Extension: Cannot launch Print dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to launch the print dialog on button click in my google chrome extension. The code seems to be working when the extension's html file is opened as a standalone file, but not when it's loaded as an extension.

HTML:
`<input id="print_page" type="button" value="Print" onclick="print_p()" />`

JavaScript: `function print_p(){ window.print();}`

Any idea as to what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: @Xan: I did try that already, but didn't turn out to be helpful for me.

I also tried a different approach, which again worked on a standalone html file and not in an extension.

Here goes(sorry about the formatting)

HTML:

<input type="image" id="print_page" title="Print/Save Report" style="height:25px;width:25px;" src="print.png" align="middle"/>

JS:
function print_p(){ window.print(); }
$("#print_page").click(function() {
        print_p();
    });

Comment: You should edit your question with that instead of commenting; besides, inline code is separated with backticks, \`. Your jQuery attempt is still wrong unless you wrap it in `$(document).ready({/*...*/});`

Comment: @Xan: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for the effort. But I've tried that as well. I beginning to wonder if a print dialog access is not allowed from an extension in chrome.

Comment: I just tested it, and it doesn't work from a popup. On other extension pages it works. Is that your case?

Comment: @Xan: What exactly do you mean by your question? Could you rephrase your question, please?

The only way it works right now is if I access it as a regular webpage on the browser.

Comment: Which extension page are you trying to do this from? A popup?

Comment: @Xan: Yup, from a popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the inline JavaScript problem that I mentioned as a duplicate, it seems that **invoking the print dialog from a popup (or a background page) is impossible**.

A workaround would be to have a "print helper" page in your extension, that opens in a normal tab and can open a print dialog.

A possible architecture:

1. On a click in a popup, data to print is being sent to the background page:

   ```
   function printClick(){
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ print: true, data: whateverYouWantToPrint });
   }
   ```

   It's routed through the background page so that you don't have to worry about popup closing.
2. In the background page, a helper page is opened:

   ```
   var printData;

   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse){
     if(request.print) {
       printData = request.data;
       chrome.tabs.create(
         { url: chrome.runtime.getURL("print.html") }
       );
     }
     // ...
   });
   ```
3. In the print helper page, a script `print.js` requests the data, formats it as required and invokes the print dialog:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ getPrintData: true }, function(response){
     formatDataIntoPage(response.data);
     window.print();
   });
   ```
4. Back in the background page, serve the data on request from print helper:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse){
     // ...
     if(request.getPrintData) {
       sendResponse({ data: printData });
     }
   });
   ```