# passing a value from background.js to popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In background.js, I create a popup like so:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    focused: true,
    width: 1170,
    url : "settings/index.html",
    type: "popup"
}, function(popup) {
    tab_app = popup.id;
    alert(tab_app);
});
```

I store the id in tab_app.

how can I pass a value from background.js to my popup?

I'm trying like that:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_app, {code: "alert("+message.add+");"});
```

but it keeps telling me that this tab id doesnt exist.. im assuming its because its a popup. will appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's your extension page, the method of choice is [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Note: you can't use the per-tab messaging of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, since this explicitly targets the content script context (that doesn't exist for extension pages). You need to use the "broadcast" `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` that will send to all other extension pages.

If you can have more than one popup-type window at a time, this may be a problem - you need some identifier to go along. You could pass it as a URL parameter or a URL hash, e.g. `"settings/index.html?id=foo"` or `"settings/index.html#foo"`. If you don't expect more than one popup-type window (you can always check if one is open before opening a new one), it doesn't matter.

If you really need dynamic code loading or execution, not just passing data (doubtful), you need to be mindful of [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

- You can dynamically load a script from your extension's package by just creating and adding a `<script>` tag to the document.
- However, you can't, by default, pass a string of code and `eval` it in the extension context. You *could* add `'unsafe-eval'` to CSP string, but that's a bad idea in general.
- Most probably, you only need some commands to be passed along with data. Pure messaging is great for it, just look at the docs.

This [old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193885/934239) may be of use - I'm using opening a new tab and passing data there to print it.

Comment: Best answer I got since I signed up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `executeScript` in the your `extension` pages. If you try to use `executeScript` in your extension page. It will show error :

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot
>   access contents of url
>   "chrome-extension://extension_id/yourPage.html".
>   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host

Now you cannot add `"chrome-extension://<extension_id>/yourPage.html"` under `permissions` in `manifest.json` because it is invalid and not allowed.
 Instead you can use `message passing`.

**background.js:**

```
  function createNewtab(){
    var targetId = null;
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changedProps) {

      if (tabId != targetId || changedProps.status != "complete")
        return;

     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(targetId, {message : "loadNewTab"},function(response){
          // do nothing yet
      });

     });

    chrome.windows.create({
       focused: true,
       width: 1170,
       url : chrome.extension.getURL("settings/index.html"),
       type: "popup"
       }, function(popup) {
           targetId = popup.tabs[0].id;       
    });
}
```

**index.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    switch (request.message){
        case "loadNewTab":
            alert("HI")
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: But I want it to be dynamic - I want to be able to use executeScript when ever it's needed

Comment: At the time of creating your window or tab, you will have to wait for it load before calling executeScript(). Once it is loaded just remove the listener and call executeScript whenever you want. I have edited the answer to remove listener

Comment: Hey, this is not working for me. the alert is not showing up.

Comment: @user3800799 I edited the answer. Check if it works now

Comment: Nope, it will not. `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` sends to content script context.

Comment: Huh. Well, it _shouldn't_ according to the docs.. Besides, it's a risky async operation there, not waiting for `targetId` to be assigned.