# Unable to call JavaScript function in html on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, google-chrome-extension

I was making a Chrome extension, for which I have an html file, a JavaScript file which opens a modified link in a new tab, the manifest file and the icon.

It works fine but now I want the javascript function to work only when the user clicks a button. So I made a button in the html file, put the js code inside a function and called the function using `onclick`.

But for some reason, it is not working. On clicking the button nothing seems to happen. I have tried reloading the extension. Also, I took a working example of a simple program in which on clicking the button, a simple "Hello world" message is displayed using alert().

This works fine when I open the html page directly in chrome but when I replaced this with the function that I made, nothing seems to happen on clicking.

Can someone please find the bug/problem?

The urltry.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<button onclick="editorial()">View Editorial</button>
<script>
function editorial()
{
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var tab_url=tabs[0].url;
    var new_url=tab_url.slice(11);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url:"http://www.discuss." + new_url});        
});
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Chrome Extensions don't allow inline event handlers. I suggest reading https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2#inline_scripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the default Content Security Policy (CSP) in Google Chrome extensions, the following is disallowed:

- Eval and related functions
- **Inline JavaScript**

The suggestion, as provided by [Google Chrome Extensions documentation on SCP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) is to place the code to a separate file and use proper binding to click event from JavaScript. See below.

Your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="editorial.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="viewEditorial">View Editorial</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Your JavaScript file, **editorial.js**

```
function editorial() {
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var tab_url=tabs[0].url;
    var new_url=tab_url.slice(11);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url:"http://www.discuss." + new_url});        
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('viewEditorial');
  if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', editorial);
  }
});
```

**Note:** don't forget that you need to declare `"tabs"` permission to be able to modify the URL. See the [tabs documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time out and helping me solve this.
I wasn't aware of the CSP as I am new to Chrome extensions.
Your solution was well-written and it did work..:)

Comment: Well, I was trying to add more features and now I have been stuck on this problem-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584927/issue-opening-new-tab-in-multiple-functions-in-javascript-for-chrome-extension
Please take a look at it and see if u can help.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your button inside the body tag, otherwise many bad things can happen and probably the browser goes in the quirks mode.

Solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function editorial()
{
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var tab_url=tabs[0].url;
    var new_url=tab_url.slice(11);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url:"http://www.discuss." + new_url});        
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="editorial()">View Editorial</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing bad will happen. Chrome automatically creates the `<body>` element and wraps the script and the button in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,

```
<body>
  <button onclick="javascript:editorial()">View Editorial</button>
</body>
```

This will work in Microsoft EDGE browser also.

Comment: It may work in Edge, but that is beside the point: this won't work in a Chrome extension.

Comment: It must be work in Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox and Maxthon also.

Comment: Working in a chrome *extension* is different than working in chrome.  Extensions explicitly disallow `onclick`.  See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).