# How to run Python script from Javascript on Apache web server?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ubuntu, apache2

Cannot get HTML file to call JavaScript function hello() on Ubuntu Apache 2. I have seen similar problems where the solution was to uncomment the #JSDIR line on the httpd.conf file but there is now only apache.conf and no similar line. I want to call the python script accesstest.py to write the current date and time to a text file from the main.js function after clicking the button on the HTML file. All of the files work correctly when run separately. How do I fix this?

*index.html HTML code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <button onclick="hello();">js function</button>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js JavaScript code:*

```
let myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';

function hello(){
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var process = spawn('python,["accesstest.py"]);
    alert('hello');
}
```

*accesstest.py Python code:*

```
import datetime
def execute():
    file = open('/path/to/file/pytest.txt', 'a+')
    file.write('test time: %s \n' % (datetime.datetime.now()))
    file.close()
execute()
```

Here is the display:

[page displays "Hello World!" with "js function button" that does nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX5GH.jpg)

Here are a couple solutions I found that didn't work for me:

[Unable to call JavaScript function in html on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580851/unable-to-call-javascript-function-in-html-on-button-click)

[How to link external javascript file onclick of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789521/how-to-link-external-javascript-file-onclick-of-button)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confusing the JS you write for the browser, and the JS you write for the CLI.

Comment: You cant execute Python in the browser like this. `spawn` might work within nodejs, but not embedded in HTML+Javascript