# window.open not working in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

i want to create a button on a popup page that redirect to google search page when clicked
so i used window.open
this is the html

```
<li> 
    <input type="image" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.com" onClick="google()">
</li>
```

and the javascript

```
function google(){ 
    window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+document.search.query.value);
}
```

this works fine when i preview the code in chrome window but in the extension popup page the button doesn't do anything, why?

Comment: put the unput element in a tag with target="blang" href=your link, this work for me

Comment: i have to use javascript because it will do the search

Comment: try this code:  chrome.windows.create({'url': 'your url', 'type': 'popup'}, function(window) {
   });

Comment: possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions cannot use inline code. Instead, get the element in Javascript. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score 0):

Please check this
[onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Chrome App [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)

I used to have this problem too, but I use [Jquery](http://jquery.com/), so far so good.

Comment: When encountering such situations, in most cases you should flag the question as duplicate and not create an answer that is just "This question answers this".