# Chrome Extension: Submit button to activate script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make an extension that runs a script when a submit button is pressed. Since Google Chrome extensions cannot have the scripts directly inside the HTML for security reasons, I need to have an external script. How do I call a function from an external script with the submit button?

This is what I've tried so far:

Here's the popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--css styling removed from here-->
        <script src="popup.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--html page is working fine, only the button is not-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="convert();">
        <p id="p2">Value</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I've also tried calling 
`popup.convert();`
, but that doesn't work either)

And here's the popup.js:

```
function convert(){
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Hello!";
}
```

I'm trying to change the p element in my extension popup, not the webpage.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
It was suggested that my question was a duplicate of this: [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

That didn't really help, although it did give me a link to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution which was semi-helpful.

**The problem with the solution on the other question is that it is not a button but a link.** (Thanks for pointing me to that topic anyway!)

Comment: @Teepeemm That's a link, not a button though.

Comment: it does not matter than it's a link. You're trying to add an event handler - you can't do that inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is a **markup** language and contains only the markup:

```html
<input id="convert-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The script should attach events to the elements once the popup document body is loaded (you reference the script in `<HEAD>` so it's executed when the `<BODY>` hasn't been parsed yet):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("convert-submit").addEventListener("click", convert);
});
```

Comment: I moved the script reference into the body and edited the code to your code, and it still isn't working. Maybe the problem also lies within `document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "Hello!";`

Comment: It is working, here's a [sample extension](https://puu.sh/ktJyR/82baeac1bc/popup.crx), you may load it manually by drag'n'dropping the downloaded file onto chrome://extensions page.

Comment: I got your code to work on my end, I'm going to check my code again. Thanks!

Comment: I got it to work by renaming the p2 element to p. I forgot the I needed to make an id for the p element. Thanks for your help!