# Chrome new tab extension and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a Chrome extension so that when I open a new tab, it is a simple page where I can make a list of To-Do's.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <script src="indexdb.js"></script>
</head>


<h2 id="toc-final">To Do List</h2>
<ul id="todoItems"></ul>
<input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" placeholder="What do you need to do?" style="width: 200px;">
<input type="submit" id="newitem" value="Add Todo Item" onclick="addTodo(); return false;">


</html>
```

I am using the javascript from http://jsfiddle.net/unclelongmao/VrS32/
My new tab has the text input box, but when I press the submit button, nothing happens. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: are you certain that `src` path is correct? You could replace `<script src="indexed.js">` with `<script>` and then add all of the contents of **indexdb.js** in between the script tags. I did and I have a little to do app working in chrome.

Comment: whats the web console say

Comment: I think it's a Chrome-specific conflict. When I open the html file from my folder, it works properly. However when it's loaded as the new tab, it does not work.

Comment: console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: Could be coz of Content Security Policy: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy