# What is wrong with my javascript that is preventing alert and/or form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to just build a simple form validation function so that I can build me google chrome extension. Later on I will be finishing up a twitter API call, but need to be able to post the values that are entered in to the input fields I have.

*Break Down*

- Chrome will only use a html, css, and javascript
- Form will use the value from the text field and the number field
- The onsubmit I have added to the form should be posting the data in the    value fields over to the javascript and having it processed
- There is one ifelse statement that I have that is checking the value of "hashtag" to make sure it is not blank
- Finally you will notice some `document.write()` that I am using to test to see where in the javascript it is not reading... nothing is working

I feel like I have gone over this a millions times. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Start javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function validator(){
 //   variables that pull the input elements from my form
    var hashtag = document.getElementById("hashtag").value;
    var tweetamy = document.getElementById("tweetamt").value;
    document.write(hashtag);
    // validating input fails if left blank if false shows alert popup, if ture write the contents of the value (this is for testing)
   if(x == "") {
    // Shows a popup when the search bar is empty
      alert("Error: Input is empty!");
      return false;
    } else {
        //prints what ever was in the hashtag element in the form
        document.write(hashtag);
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
<!-- End javascript -->
</head>
<body>
<h3> Search hashtags on twitter (ex: #winning)</h3>
<br>
<!-- The start of my form, has an "onsubmit" action-->
<form method="post" onsubmit="javascript:validator();">
<!-- Used as a search bar -->
  Search:<input type="text" name="search" id="hashtag" />
  <br><br>
  <!-- Used to set the amount of tweets in the last hour you want to pull -->
  Tweets:<input type="number" name="key_amt" min="0" max="100" value="1"id="tweetamt" />
  <br><br>
  <!-- Just a button -->
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<!-- end of form -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the developer console say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all your JavaScript code to an external file.

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both
>   inline script blocks and inline event handlers.
>
> The first restriction wipes out a huge class of cross-site scripting
>   attacks by making it impossible for you to accidentally execute script
>   provided by a malicious third-party. It does, however, require you to
>   write your code with a clean separation between content and behavior.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Answer (score 1):

in

```
if(x == "") {
```

'x' is not defined, I think you want:

```
if(hashtag == "") {
```

Comment: btw you can use hashtag === ""