# How can I load a page in Google Chrome using an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to load a new page in current tab by clicking on link displayed in the Chrome extension. How can I do that?

I tried assigning the onClick attribute but it does not work for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the current tab, and then update it. [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) is the API to use.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: "http://example.com/"});
});
```

Note that this does *not* need a `"tabs"` permission.

---

And in general, regarding the `onClick` problems, see [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983/934239).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi). Just add a listener for click event which executes the script in the tab. Then this script will change the url.

Comment: That's quite a roundabout way to do it.

Comment: Another issue is that you need permissions to do the injection in the first place. `"activeTab"` will help, but this needs to be addressed in the answer.