# Chrome extension message passing from background script to content script is not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message, message-passing

I am trying chrome plugin creation [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
My code is as follows:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Sending Messages Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Send a Message to background.js from contentscript.js and send reply",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    // "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<div style="width:200px">
    <button id="button">Color all the divs</button>
</div>
```

popup.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    // alert("in popup.js");
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
      message: "coming from popup"
    });
  }
}
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender) {
    alert("Contentscript has received a message from from background script: '" + request.message + "'");
    return true;
});
```

background.js:

```
var backgroundScriptMessage = " purple monkey dishwasher";

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    alert("Background script has received a message from contentscript:'" + request.message + "'");
    returnMessage(request.message);
});

function returnMessage(messageToReturn) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
      var joinedMessage = messageToReturn + backgroundScriptMessage;
      alert("Background script is sending a message to contentscript:'" + joinedMessage +"'");
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
    });
}
```

When I unpack the plugin in chrome extensions, and click on the generated icon, I see 2 alerts

1. Background script has received a message from contentscript:'coming from popup'
2. Background script has received a message from contentscript:'coming from popup' purple monkey dishwasher

and the third popup which is present in the contentscript is never shown. I tried searching for the error but no luck. Does anybody has a solution?

Comment: Have you tried uncomment this line `// "permissions": ["tabs"],`?

Comment: Also, what's your background.js file?

Comment: i tried uncommenting `"permissions": ["tabs"],`, it didn't work

Comment: Could you try replacing `.onclick=` with `.addEventListener('click'`?  Your problem could be related to [http://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983/2336725](onClick within Chrome Extension not working).

Answer (score 0):

When querying current active tab, don't forget to add `currentWindow: true`

```
function returnMessage(messageToReturn) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var joinedMessage = messageToReturn + backgroundScriptMessage;
          alert("Background script is sending a message to contentscript:'" + joinedMessage +"'");
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
    });
}
```

And please use `runtime.onMessage` instead of `extension.onMessage`.

BTW, you can also use `sender.tab.id` to get sender tab id in `runtime.onMessage` listener, then you will not need to query tabs state.

Comment: He might not know to which tab the needs to send the message to

Comment: @gautamscoders, update, the root cause should be you forget `currentWindow` property when querying current tab.

Comment: I inserted `currentWindow: true` still it is not working and  yes i have used `chrome.runtime` in contentscript.js.

Comment: @gautamscoders, how come? Make sure your content script in running on the current active page

Comment: okay @HaibaraAi here is what i have observed. When i unpack the plugin, switch to a tab and run the plugin, contentscript alert is not shown. Whereas   before running plugin & after switching to a tab, if i refresh the tab and than run the plugin, It works perfectly fine.

Comment: @gautamscoders, that is definitely by design. If you run the extension after the page has been loaded, then by default your content script isn't loaded in that page, which means you can't receive anything in that page. You should refresh that page to force the content script to load, or you can query all tabs then call `tabs.executeScript` to explicitly insert content scripts.