# How to pass a message from a Chrome extension background script to a content script in JavaScript via the context menu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am working on a Chrome extension using JavaScript and need to be able to pass a message from a background script to a content script using a custom entry in the context menu as a trigger for this.

**manuscript.json**

```html
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Admin Tools",
 "version": "0.3",
 
 "permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "tabs",
  "activeTab"
 ],
 
 "content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
   "js": ["lead_partner_search_content.js"]
  }
 ],
 
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["admin_search.js", "company_id_search.js","order_id_search.js","lead_partner_search.js"]
 }
}
```

**lead_partner_search.js** (background script)

```html
//lead_partner_search.js

var backgroundScriptMessage = " purple monkey dishwasher";

function returnMessage(messageToReturn) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var joinedMessage = messageToReturn + backgroundScriptMessage;
          alert("Background script is sending a message to contentscript:'" + joinedMessage +"'");
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
 "title": "Search leads by company name",
 "contexts": ["selection"],
 "onclick": returnMessage("test")
})
```

**lead_partner_search_content.js** (content script)

```html
//lead_partner_search_content.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender) {
    alert("Contentscript has received a message from from background script: '" + request.message + "'");
    return true;
});
```

Following [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473516/chrome-extension-message-passing-from-background-script-to-content-script-is-not) example from Stack Overflow, this should show one alert as:

> Background script is sending a message to contentscript:'test purple monkey dishwasher'

And then a second as:

> Contentscript has received a message from from background script: 'test purple monkey dishwasher'

However, what actually happens is when the extension is loaded, the first message alert appears instantly and nothing further happens even when triggering the context menu entry.

I am unsure as to why this is and do not wholly understand message passing in Google Chrome despite searching on this and other sites for information.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `onclick` assignment in a `function() { }` wrapper?  Doesn't seem like it should matter but sometimes JavaScript is weird like that. `"onclick": function() { returnMessage("test"); }`

Comment: That has prevented the issue with the alert flashing up as soon as the extension is loaded and I can now trigger the first alert with the context menu entry, however, I still receive no second alert, it seems like the message isn't being picked up by the content script.

Comment: Do you get any errors or messages in the console?

Comment: No, after triggering the context menu entry the console remains blank

Comment: Try adding two `console.log` commands: one at the top of your content script (to make sure the content script is being loaded) and the second inside the `onMessage` listener.

Comment: Adding `console.log("content")` to the top of my content file causes the console to print `content` however adding `console.log(joinedMessage)` underneath the declaration of the aforementioned variable does not print anything when triggering the context menu entry however still produces the alert

Comment: @EthanField are you saying if you put a `console.log` after the `var joinedMessage` line, the console message doesn't print but the alert right after it does?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150764/discussion-between-ethan-field-and-freginold).

Comment: You should not `return true;` in your `runtime.onMessage` listener unless you actually intend to send a response using `sendResponse`, which you clearly don't do in this code.

Comment: Don't, by default, use `alert()` for debugging. It can cause/resolve timing issues/race conditions which can be harder to debug. If you're not going to use the actual debugger, then use `console` output. The *occasional* `alert()` might be acceptable, but it should not be your default, go to way to show progress. If for no other reason, `console` output allows you to go back over the output in the console multiple times rather, than having to remember what happened/was displayed in `alert()` and in what order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advice from the comments I was able to change the background script to the below:

```
//lead_partner_search.js
function returnMessage() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"});
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Search leads by company name",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
    "onclick": returnMessage
})
```

And to my content script to the below:

```
//lead_partner_search_content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender) {
    console.log("Contentscript has received a message from background script: '" + request.greeting + "'");
});
```

This produces the desired output in the console of:

> Contentscript has received a message from background script: 'hello'

Based on what I now understand it seems that I was calling a part of the message which didn't exist `request.message` where I should have been calling `request.greeting` as this is what I was declaring when sending the message from the background script.