# Linking JavaScript correctly in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I have a chrome extension, yet the JavaScript is not loading correctly. I tried linking a file but failed miserably. Have any ideas on how I can make buttons run functions when clicked? <script> tags do not work in this and the buttons do nothing, but the initial JavaScript does run... Here is my code

manifest.json(I think it works correctly):

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Getting started example",
"description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
 ]

  }
```

popup.html(Functions in JavaScript don't link to this):

```
<body style = "margin:10px">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<style>
//Fancy styles
large{font-size:30px}
span{}
.input-group{width:400px}
</style>
<!-- title -->
<large>
SpeedyURLs
</large>
<hr/>
<!-- Code that won't link with JavaScript -->
<div id = "stuff">

</div>
<div class = "input-group" id = "content"><input class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter a URL here. Ex: https://www.google.com"/><span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" style = "font-size:20px;width:50px;color:black" id="basic-addon1" onclick = "addNew()">+        </span></div>
<button onclick = 'document.write("HELLO")'>YAS</button>
</body>
```

popup.js(The functions that don't link):

```
function open(url){
window.open(url)}
function addNew(){
document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML+'<div class = "input-group" id = "content"><input class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter a URL here. Ex: https://www.google.com"/><span  style = "font-size:20px;width:50px;color:black" class="input-group-addon btn btn-danger" id="basic-addon1">x</span></div>'}
```

icon.png(Default image no code in it, works fine)

So, the functions in JS won't link to HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), inline JavaScript will not be executed.

You could

1. Relax the default policy. See [Inline Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script) for more details.
2. Remove `onclick` in `popup.html` and move that logic to your `popup.js`, code would look like (say your button id is `buttonId0`)

   ```
   document.getElementById("buttonId0").addEventListener("click", function() {
       // Your logic here
   }, false);
   ```