# Hyperlinked Images not displaying on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Im creating a simple chrome extension which has two tick boxes, when clicked they should show the hyperlinked image. The html file works by itself but when I add it to the extension the images dont show. Anyone know whats wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
      function toggleVisibility(id) {
       var el = document.getElementById(id);

       if (el.style.visibility=="visible") {
              el.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
         else {
              el.style.visibility="visible";
            }
         }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
        }   
        .popupContainerDiv{
            width:350px;
            min-height: 150px;

        }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <label for="chkyt">YouTube</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkyt" onChange="toggleVisibility('imgyt');" /><br/>


        <label for="chkfb">Facebook</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkfb"  onChange="toggleVisibility('imgfb');" />
        <hr />

        <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img id="imgyt" src="ytlogo.png" alt="YouTube" height="100" width="150" style="visibility:hidden"></a>

        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img id="imgfb" src="fblogo.png" alt="Facebook" height="100" width="100" style="visibility:hidden"></a>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Embedded js code doesn't work inside extension pages. Move it to a separate file. I think there should have been an error shown in the devtools console (F2 key), don't forget to always check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add inline Javascript in extensions. You need to separate javascript into js file

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it by adding a listener to the js file