# onclick is not working in chrome app?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

Hi I am creating a chrome app. I create a click event on button using java script. It is working fine in simple html pages but not working in chrome app.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="btn01" value="OK">
        </form>

        <p>Click the "Disable" button to disable the "OK" button:</p>

        <button onclick="disableElement()">Disable</button>

        <script>
            function disableElement() {
                document.getElementById("btn01").disabled = true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that onclick event is compatible with mobile environments.

Comment: did you check this post,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working You should add event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add inline JavaScript in Chrome Extensions. Instead, you need create an external JavaScript file where you can add the event listener. Something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 document.getElementById('disable-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("btn01").disabled = true;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" id="btn01" value="OK">
  </form>

  <p>Click the "Disable" button to disable the "OK" button:</p>
  <button id="disable-button">Disable</button>
</body>
</html>
```