# Chrome Extension: How do I change the color of an HTML canvas using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on building my first Google Chrome extension but have run into a problem.

I simply want the extension to make a popup window when an icon is clicked.
This window will itself display a canvas thats color will change, to green, when a button is clicked.

I've tested my code on websites such as Codepen and it works fine but not when I actually run it in Chrome.

All of my extension's files are in the same folder.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> <script src="popup.js"> </script> </head>
<canvas id="canvs" style="border: 2px solid black"></canvas>
    <input type = "button" value = "color" onclick="colorChange()">
</html>
```

JavaScript (popup.js):

```
function colorChange(){
    var can = document.getElementById("canvs");
    can.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No messages on the console?

Comment: Try adding some debugging information - for example make the function 
`function colorChange(event) {
    var can = document.getElementById("canvs");
    can.style.backgroundColor = "green";
 console.log('colorChange', event, can);
}`

what does the console output when you click the button?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the console. The error message I get it is "popup.html:19 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution." – where line 19 is <input type = "button" value = "color" onclick="colorChange()">

Comment: Additional duplicate: [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Extension Does not support inline javaScript

You should be

```
<input id="color" type = "button" value = "color" >
```

```js
$("#color").click(function(){
 // your code
});
```

```js
// popup.js
window.onload= function(){
 var color = document.getElementById("color");
 color.onclick = function(){
  // your code
 }
}
```

Comment: You can see installation error in    chrome : //extensions/

Comment: That's the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I'm still very new to this. What is the purpose of the "$" in the above code? I still get this error in the console even after using your suggestions: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Do I need to reference jQuery in my html file?

Comment: Jquery，a JavaScript library

Comment: Ok cool. Is there an easy way to do this without accessing jquery?

Comment: I've updated the answer