# Chrome extension: How to add a button to a page on a web site and add a click handler to it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, onclick

I am trying to dynamically add a button to a page on a third-party website, and add a click handler to the button, using a Chrome extension. I have read [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working), added the handler in a separate `js` file.

The problem is that Chrome tries to find that `js` file in the web server, not in the extension. So, 404 happens.

Let's say the web page is "http://www.somecompany.com/somepage.html". My extension code is like the following.

```
    var aButton = document.createElement('button');
    aButton.id = "aButton";
    thatDiv.appendChild(aButton);

    var aScript = document.createElement("script");
    aScript.src="aButtonHandler.js";
    thatDiv.appendChild(aScript);
```

Chrome tries to load "http://www.somecompany.com/aButtonHandler.js", and of course the real web site does not have that script, so 404 happens. How can I add a button to a web site and execute `alert("hello");` when the button is clicked?

---

Added

I added the code in `aButtonHandler.js` to the end of the content script itself, but nothing happened. What is wrong?

content script.js

```
addButton();

function addButton()
{
    //adds a button by the code above.
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var theButton = document.getElementById('aButton');
    theButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('damn');
    });
});
```

---

Added

This worked.

content script.js

```
addButton();

function addButton()
{
    //adds a button by the code above.
    aButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('damn');
    });
}
```

Comment: The question you've linked is for own pages of the extension like the popup or options page. For content script you don't need to load a separate file. Simply attach the listener in your content script.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. I have added the code to the question.

Comment: Maybe the id conflicts with something on the page. Maybe something else is interfering. Maybe you didn't reload the tab so the content script is not injected. Simply set a breakpoint in devtools on your content script and see what happens, what are the values of the variables and elements and so on.

Comment: Ah. Success. Just called the `addEventListener` directly. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Yep, by default the content script is loaded **after** DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `setInterval` function to check `<button>` element is exists, if not create and append the `<button>` element.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() { 
    if(document.getElementById('aButton')) {
        //  clearInterval(myVar);
        return false;
    } else {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName("assignedToUsers")[0]) {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Test";
            button.id = "aButton";
            button.type = "button";
            document.getElementsByClassName("assignedToUsers")[0].appendChild(button);

            var theButton = document.getElementById('aButton');
            theButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("ms-TextField-field")[0].value);
            });
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll Useing set interval function  and check button element because button element not exist than button append otherwise button not append