# Load js data onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to load these field values via extension popup when the anchor link is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: do you have filldata defined anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: @wOxxOm This question is not related to `onclick` not working in Chrome. The function is just not written/called correctly.

Comment: You can't know it's not related. It's a typical mistake in extension development. Anyway, the question doesn't provide complete info so no need to answer it prematurely.

Comment: @wOxxOm To me it seems OP is trying to fill two input fields with data `onclick` of a button.  However, the function is not being declared/called correctly, and is obviously not working.  (See the next answer, which does the same thing using jQuery)

Comment: No need to argue over an incomplete question. The correct action is to urge the OP to provide the missing info - whether the code runs in the extension popup or whatever.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion yes i am trying to run it in an extension popup which will inject onto a page and fill the data when clicked

Answer (score 1):

Using pure jQuery since you're already using some of it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fill").click(function(){
    $("#user").val("name@email.com")
    $("#pw").val("pass123")
  })
})
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoxey/4gdpehde/)

Comment: That works but i need it to  be able to load via an anchor link/button as I'm putting it into a chrome extension (popup.html)

Comment: This answer assumes you should add `id="fill"` to your html of the link.