# Can't document.getElementById("page").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension. And I can't change the text in div. Can you help me please? I can't find what's wrong here.

manifest.json:

```
{
      "name": "Test",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "description": "Test app",
      "permissions": [ "background", "tts", "storage" ],

      "background": { "scripts": ["my.js"] },

      "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "my.html"
      },

      "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

my.js:

```
function StartUp(){
    var data ="dater";
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = data;
}
```

my.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test app</title>
    <script src="my.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page" onclick="StartUp()">
hello
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your `script` tag just before `</body>`.

Comment: @Marwelln The function is called on click, script placement doesn't make any difference.

Comment: are the html and js files in the same directory; If so, try pasting the code(my.js) inside the html itself within <script> tags

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Have you placed something like `console.log("js file loaded");` into your JS file to make sure that it is loading? Is there an error when running this page? If so, please post the error message in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: @JJJ that's right)

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram yes they are I was trying that as well, it didn't help

Comment: @nicolascolman no

Comment: i rebuid your code and add to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild your code and all OK:

my.js:

```
function StartUp(ev){
    var data ="dater";
    ev.target.textContent = data;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  let page = document.getElementById('page');
  page.addEventListener('click',StartUp)

})
```

my.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="my.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
       hello
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jerey,show your  errors in  chrome://extensions/ in your app.

Comment: Yea it works, but I am getting the error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (my.js:7)". I've changed only my.js and now the code is like: [code] function StartUp(e){
    var data ="dater";
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = data;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', StartUp);
});
[/code]

Comment: Well don't put the code in comments. Edit the question.