# How to use ajax in Google Chrome extention

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-chrome-extension, insert

i want to insert data to server using ajax in my chrome extension so my users can sign up to use my extension.
i am desperately finding solution not not find the example

when i code ajax on popup.html i got this error
"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lXzxt12nj+7ATE1j5ucGnYo1VkLZpNS/cGA9SL9nCv0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

popup.html Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  body {
   width:300px;
   font-size:12px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="uname">
 <input type="text" id="pass" name="upass">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" id="btn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="check.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btn").click(function(){
  
  var btn =$('#btn').val();
  var name= $('#name').val();
  var pas = $('#pass').val();
  $.ajax({
   data :{btn: btn, name : name, pas: pas},
   method="POST",
   url:"http://localhost/status/index.php",
   success : function(data){
    lb.val(data);
   }
  });


 });
}
</script>
```

index.php code which is on server

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



if(isset($_POST['byn'])){
 $localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 $insert = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO usercheck VALUES('','$name','$pass','1111,'$localIP')");

}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: See the linked thread for explanations and solutions. In short, don't use inline script code.