# Input that searches google

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I am making a extension theme for my Chromebook that searches coding sites (like this site, w3schools, ect.) How sould I make it? This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
<input id="input1">
<button onclick="searchGoogle()">Search Google</button>
<script>
function searchGoogle() {
        var one = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var two = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + one;
        window.location = two;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code doesn't work

When it runs, this pops up:

[(Image of my code running)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CSL1.png)

Is my code wrong?

Any help will be aapreciated.

EDIT

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="searchgoogle.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>    
<input id="input1">
<button id="link">Search Google</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {

        function searchGoogle() {
        var one = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var two = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + one;
        window.location = two;
    }


    });
});
```

Didn't work either

Comment: Try changing the link to https.. does that work?

Comment: So how exactly does it not work? The screenshot looks like what you'd expect that form to look like. What happens when you click the button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: Nope, and I don't think it is about the link

Comment: I tried adding a listener, that didnt work either

Comment: did you use inspector to debug?

Comment: Yes, it says " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (searchgoogle.js:4)"

Comment: And I did look at "onClick within Chrome Extension not working"

Comment: The function `searchGoogle` is declared but never called

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the corrrect devtools console. The popup page declared in browser_action is a separate window with its own DOM and devtools which you can open by rightclicking the popup, then clicking 'inspect' in the context menu.

Comment: @JJJ nothing happens

Comment: The answer by Iván Nokonoko awnwered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the function `searchGoogle` inside the listener function but it is never called. Try with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {

        //there is no need to declare a new function here.

        var one = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var two = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(one);
        window.location = two;



    });
});
```