# Can't solve Content Security Policy error in extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

No matter what I do, my popup keeps return this error, "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-RtrTopek4SlRj1jJ/Err6CDLFxdi7+ka5mWfZxTAPfY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I've tried everything to fix it, including pasting the source JS and running it seperately, I've used the content_security_policy in the manifest, but that doesn't seem to work. Are there any options I can try to fix this? My manifest.json is below,

```
    {
  "name": "Stellar Lumens Price Tracker",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Display the price of Stellar Lumens right in your browser.",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Stellar Lumens Price Tracker",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "stellar.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts":["price.js", "popup.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

HTML and JS Code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 750px; height: 400px">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div id="tradingview_e4c1e"></div>
      <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BINANCE-XLMUSD/" 
        rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">XLMUSD chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      new TradingView.widget(
      {
        "width": 750,
        "height": 400,
        "symbol": "BINANCE:XLMUSD",
        "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "Dark",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "container_id": "tradingview_e4c1e"
    });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use inline js, use a separate file ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)), 2. never trust remote code to run in the highly privileged context of an extension because the server may be hacked or MitM-spoofed. Put the js file in your extension package and load it locally.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!