# Open extension html page from chrome popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with `browser_action` popup:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {                   
      "16": "images/icon16.png",        
      "24": "images/icon24.png",        
      "32": "images/icon32.png"         
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

The `popup.html` has these items:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

I want to implement the following: when a user clicks on `Item 2` I would like to open my extension's `item2.html` page in new browser tab.

I do not really know where to dig, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Either add `<a href="item2.html" target="_blank">Item 2</a>` or use chrome.tabs.create in your popup script.

Comment: If I go the second route, how do I handle on click event in popup.js script? I get all kind of "Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
" exceptions, so maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Use a [separate script file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457). Also, I think it's best to start off an existing extension e.g. one of the [official samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).