# Refused to evaluate a string as Javascript in chrome extension, in pdfjs

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, pdf.js

I am working on a chrome extension which uses PDFJS, but PDFJS latest release have some javascript which is returning JS as string

```
Function("return this")()
```

which is not allowed in chrome extension. so it giving following error

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
```

So, how can i bundle pdfjs files in chrome extension to get rid of this issue?

Comment: You'll have to modify the default CSP, I guess. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm it helped!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding 'unsafe-eval' option to content_security_policy in manifest.json.

Comment: This is not really correct. This is a pretty dangerous permission to add and will make approval from google take a lot longer without addressing the root problem. Pinning the PDFjs version is a better answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is within a lib used by PDFJS. Using the version `2.1.266` should fix the problem.

Here is a more detailed thread about the issue and other workarounds: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11036