# Using Google Tag Manager with Google Analytics to track a Chrome Extension (2020)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am working on a chrome extension, and I would like to be able to track metrics with google analytics. I believe the easiest way to do that would be through tag manager, and I have found [this](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/gtmtips-deploy-gtm-chrome-extension/) tutorial that explains how to implement google tag manager in a chrome extension. However, just following this tutorial isn't working for me, and I have a few questions.

- Is it possible to track a chrome extension using Google Analytics? If so, I have only seen tutorials using Universal Analytics, but is it possible using Google Analytics 4? It is recommended to start out with GA4 now, and I would like to do that if possible.
- How would I set up a data stream? A web data stream requires a valid URL, which doesn't really apply to an extension. I have a separate website that I am working on and I can include that URL, but my goal is to track the extension, not the website.
- When debugging in GTM, it now requires you to add a URL on which to debug. My extension runs on amazon.com but when I enter amazon.com as the URL I get a 404, probably because the tracking code doesn’t actually apply to amazon, but to the iframe that is injected when I am on amazon. What would I do here?

I have it set up so that the GTM code is in a separate js file that is injected into the iframe html code at the end of the head tag. I have modified the CSP in the manifest to allow requests to google analytics and google tag manager. And when building the tag in GTM, I set the fields `checkProtocolTask` to `false`, `page` to a custom url, and `path` to `{{Page Path}}` as the above tutorial and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382346/how-i-can-insert-google-tag-manager-to-popup-in-chrome-extension) have suggested. For now I have my GA account set up with GA4, and I'm using a web data stream. I have the GTM tag as a GA4 configuration and I have made sure I included the correct measurement ID. I'm having a hard time finding any information about using GTM/GA in a chrome extension, and so any answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, for anyone still wondering how to add Analytics to a Chrome Extension, I've figured it out.

First of all, you have to use Universal Analytics (analytics.js), Google Analytics 4 (gtag.js) will not work. It doesn't handle tasks, and we will need to disable certain tasks in order to send hits. Also, it may be possible to use UA with Google Tag Manager, but after I got so deep into figuring this out I decided it would just be easier for me to implement tracking in the code myself. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6_C3VqkVnA) that shows you how to set up a UA property in Google Analytics.

In my code, I created a JavaScript file ga.js, with the typical google analytics tracking code that looks like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-X", "auto");
```

with two slight modifications: add the 'https:' in front of the google analytics url, and of course add your own UA property id.

After that, we have to disable checkProtocolTask by adding

```
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);
```

This disables file protocol checking, which we need because google analytics aborts the hit if it's not originating from an http or https protocol (this is originating from a 'chrome-extension://' protocol). I also found I needed to disable checkStorageTask in the same manner, though I am less sure why I needed to do that. All of the resources I have found say that only the checkProtocolTask needs to be disabled to use GA in a CE. My best guess is because my extension isn't a popup, but an injected iFrame, so the cookie permissions are different. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706518/set-checkstoragetask-to-null-in-analytics-js) about it, but haven't gotten any responses. In order to still track user sessions without the use of cookies, I used localStorage to store the ga clientId, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#using_localstorage_to_store_the_client_id).

I then linked this javascript file at the bottom of the head section of my html file, and added

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
```

to my manifest.json. And Voila! It's working.

Some last minute notes: I definitely recommend using analytics_debug.js while debugging analytics, and if you are still having trouble figuring out the issue then try setting `window.ga_debug = {trace: true};` to get an even more detailed log in the console. Also, when sending pageviews, it is important to include the page in the hit as so: `ga('send', 'pageview', '/popup');`.

This was an absolute headache to figure out, so I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Could you link a complete example of what your `ga.js` file looks like after your modifications?

Comment: Is this a solution working with manifest V2 or V3?

Comment: @akds this was with V2. I'm no longer actively working on the project, so I'm not sure of the intricacies of doing this in V3.

Comment: Thanks @MRB, it seems like I might have to ask about V3 as I can't find any info on it, and it would be great to have some analytics. The tricky part is that not only V3 is a change but also the new V4 for Google Analytics which relies on Google tags and Web streams now

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked perfectly for me (and I also had to disable the check storage task, weird). Thanks again!