# How to use Google Tag Assistant for another Chrome extension

Tags: google-tag-manager, web-frontend

I am using Google Tag Manager in a Chrome Extension to monitor user behavior, but Google Tag Assistant only takes a website as input anybody knows how to use it for another extension?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511312/using-google-tag-manager-with-google-analytics-to-track-a-chrome-extension-2020 And you're not supposed to be able to use GTM with Chrome extensions.

Comment: Thx Well I was able to use GTM in a Chrome Extension just can't use the Assistant.

Comment: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/gtmtips-deploy-gtm-chrome-extension/ 
and here is the guide i followed to get GTM to work for Chrome Ext