# How do I load a page in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is the error I get

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

The code I am writing

```
window.location.href="../settings.html";
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: Could you please tell from where you are initiating this piece of code? Can you add some more relevant code so that we could help you better?