# Chrome extension error when adding script tags to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My problem is, when developing a chrome extension, I am getting error;

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob:
>   filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline'
>   keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-+BWoieEB23JsqONQi994gklHUNPq5RCtit+I45ejZPU='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

When I try to add  to the html.
What can I do?

Comment: Use a separate js file. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457).