# Key press is not being detected (Javascript & HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, keycode

So I'm making a Chrome Extension and am currently making it so that if you press the "A" key, then an alert pops up.  I've gotten this to work when I open my HTML file through my extension folder.  However, when I unpack my folder into a Chrome extension and test it as a Chrome extension, the script won't run.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyPress, false);

    function checkKeyPress(key){
      if (key.keyCode =="65"){
        alert("test")
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use a separate js file as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457). P.S. use the [**correct** devtools for the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code --->

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 65){
         alert()}})
}
</script>
```