# How to execute javascript on chrome extension load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Background**

I developed a small chrome extension which is implemented as popup.html and popup.js (based on Google's provided sample). What I would like to do is implement the equivalent of an  method such that when I click the extension icon, the popup.html is loaded and the popup.js therein is called, containing a someMethod() function. As of right now I observe no inline javascript executed at all upon page, even in placement of a script element with inline code.

**Use**

At a higher level, what I am trying to do is prepopulate values into the popup.html upon load based on data I have in localStorage whenever the extension is instantiated/clicked.

**What I have tried that has not worked**:

- inline execution of javascript within popup.html
- referenced ... in
  popup.html
- a 'does it work at all' of ...
  in popup.html

**Other notes**

What I observe is that no javascript ever appears to be executed as referenced upon a popup.html / chrome extension instantiation. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's as simple as `<script src="popup.js"></script>`. More info about embedded scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457). Also note, the popup has its own devtools, accessible by right-clicking inside the popup.

Comment: Yes, operator error :( - I had a bug elsewhere I didn't realize. Thank you for your prompt response, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Operator error - I had a bug elsewhere I didn't realize, wOxxOm answer worked!