# Extension Comment

Tags: html

I'm creating an extension for google chrome that when the user clicks the "Copy!" button, execute this function on the web page

Comment: FYI you might have much better luck tagging your question with chrome extension and changing the title to something like "How to run script on page from chrome extension context"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

`onclick="execute()"` this won't run, since you can't use inline `JavaScript` in html file for chrome extensions.

So trying adding `click` event listenter on copy button using JavaScript, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', execute);      
});
```

Comment: just remove `onclick="execute()"` all together. It would look like this:` <input type="button" value="Copy!">` You don't need this, since click event and the event handler `execute` is added in JS.

Comment: Is giving error in js:                                                                                         
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (popup.js:2)

Comment: updated the snippet. just replace 'button' with 'input'.