# How to show webcam video on Chrome extension's dropdown?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, video-streaming, webcam

I want to put video tag on the dropdown menu of Chrome extension.
In my `dropdown.html` of the extension I'm creating, I put the `video` tag and `script` tag.

```html
    <video autoplay="true" id="cameraLive"></video>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video = document.querySelector("#cameraLive");

        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                })
                .catch(function (err0r) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                });
        }
    </script>
```

When I open `dropdown.html` in browser, it works fine.
But on extension, it does not work. The error says:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates
the following Content Security Policy directive:
"script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:".
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-H1sZS7OyOYQVjQrWlBxGG3pZLyVentv7JICMQKRUwf8='),
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable
inline execution.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Use a separate js file, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457).