# How to fix chrome extension : Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add the event click listener on button using jQuery.

When i click the button its works fine but getting the below error on
chrome://extension

`Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Here is my chrome extension popup :
[image]

I have added the click event listener just hide and show using jQuery.

But its work fine  getting error in chrome://extension.

Included JavaScript file in popup html

[image]

Comment: You probably look at the old error in chrome://extensions page. Click `clear all` button to remove it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I have cleared the error still getting the popup inspect tool

Comment: It means the error is elsewhere, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721457).

Comment: Yes, I have already followed that, created one external js file and included in popup.html. The event click listener is working but getting the error in console.

Comment: Is the any changes in menifest.json ?

Comment: You're not showing us the entire code so we can't help. The only explanation I have is that you didn't fix all occurrences.

Comment: I have shared the one image in that i have link the script file name : home-scipt.js in home script.js i have write the some js code like add event listener in both normal js and jquery js  Like : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("showMysite")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {

        document.getElementsByClassName(".panelDiv")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName(".mysites")[0].style.display = "none";

    });
});

Comment: This is not the entire code. Your HTML must have an inline js handler somewhere.

Comment: Solved the error, Can't use the href="javascript:void(0) in anchor tag"