# Creating a chrome extension with web application features

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just started learning how to build a basic chrome extension. I see many chrome extensions which have extensive functionality like a full fledged web app. For example, when I click on a particular chrome extension, it opens a new tab with a URL chrome-extension://gibberish/filename.html. This page functions like a complete web app. Here is an example chrome extension which does image compression: [image: Sample Chrome Extension]

From my research, it looks like a combination of chrome extension development bundled with NodeJs. But, I am unable to find enough information about this to find a course to learn myself. If I had to develop a similar application, where do I start? Can any web application be transformed into a chrome extension or is there a specific way to go about it?

Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be possible to convert any web application into an extension, and usually it's trivial or at least straightforward, which is probably why there's no specific information. You simply copy the files and fix the issues as they start to appear. The most common one is the [inline js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-or-inline-script-isnt-working-in-extension).

Comment: @wOxxOm Does that mean any web application that is based on HTML/JS and coupled with a server-side technology like PHP can be converted to a chrome extension?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. You probably will have to make minor or trivial changes.

Comment: @wOxxOm Server side code like PHP needs a web server config to run on. When we deploy our app in the chrome web store, it won't run, isn't it?

Comment: Your extension can connect to your existing web server. Or you can rewrite the server-side parts but unlike the web app part this one may be impossible depending on what exactly your backend does.

Comment: Did you try the [getting started](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/) guide?