# Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, fastapi

I have built a chrome extension for retrieving data from backend, but something wrong out there, the error appear. **Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".**.
I'm writing my backend using fastapi, and the frontend using angular.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: See [onclick or inline script isn't working in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)