# chrome.tts.speak has undefined properties when used in service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, text-to-speech

I'm trying to add a sound to my chrome extension. It is my understanding it must be done in a service worker and that is where I have it:

```
 chrome.tts.speak("Hit has been queued",{"lang": "en-US","rate":2.0});
```

However, when this executes I get this error:

caught error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'speak')

It almost looks like a syntax error in the argument list but I don't see it. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong? TIA

**Updated HTML page without running as an extension**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Alert
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            chrome.tts.speak("Hit added to queue",{"lang":"US-en","rate":2.0});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Updated per suggestion**

alert.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Alert
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="alert.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

alert.js

```
chrome.tts.speak("Hit added to queue",{"lang":"US-en","rate":2.0});
```

Comment: This API doesn't work in a service worker.

Comment: Interesting. I read where it MUST be in a service worker. In any case what is the alternative? Thanks.

Comment: There's no alternative. You'll have to open a new tab/window with your extension html file, so that inside its script you can use this API.

Comment: I've create a new HTML page using that interface (OP is updated). I still get the same error when loading that page directly in Chrome (no extension).

Comment: You need to load it via chrome.tabs.create({url: 'page.html'}) so that it has chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: I loaded it using crtl+o. I just want to see it it works before adding it to my extension.

Comment: Well, you can't do it.

Comment: OK, so now I am struggling with content security. I added this to my manifest 3: "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' unsafe-inline 'alert.html'"
  }  The error I get it on unsafe-inline. I don't know how to specify a local html file.

Comment: Use a separate js file: [onclick or inline script isn't working in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)

Comment: I guess I don't understand. I have that HTML file in my extension directory. I load it using chrome.tabs.create({url:"alert.html"}) from my background script.

Comment: The link I gave shows how to load a separate js file e.g. you alert.html should have `<script src="alert.js"></script>` and the code should be inside alert.js

Comment: That is what I've done. My background script uses chrome.tabs.create to load alert.html. As you suggested I load the script (alert.js) from a separate source file. I still get the same error. See updated OP.

Comment: Remove `type="application/x-javascript"` and make sure you have tts in permissions in manifest.json.

Comment: That was it. Weird error message. Thanks.