# JS Library (or a way to use pure JS) for using sortable items (drag & drop) in Chrome Extension pop up windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I keep getting CSP violation warnings like the one below when trying different libraries to add sortable items/ drag & drop functionalities to the Chrome Extension I am building:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, 
so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The extension is using V3 of the manifest. I've got this in the configuration:

```
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';"
      },
```

Does anyone know a way to add this functionality to a Chrome Extension?
I'd rather use pure JS but after having tried some of these options I continue to get `unsafe-eval` related errors in Chrome.

Like the one below for example which is very simple but seems to be using some sort of `eval` variation and Chrome won't let me use this for my extension:
(I'll use JSFiddle links so as not to burden you visually with too much code)

https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/028mw6v3/50/

Works ok but not when I add this to my Extension.

Also tried this one with "SortableJS" library and I get the same `unsafe-eval` problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/981Lygfx/11/

Does this mean that sortable/drag & drop functions have to absolutely use `eval` or its variations?

Comment: All code must be included within the extension in ManifestV3, not loaded from a server.

Comment: In that case shouldn't this https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/028mw6v3/49/ work with the extension since it is not loading any code from a server from what I see.
Also I tried downloading all the SortableJS code and loading from local to run on the extension and still I get CSP issues. There must be something ```eval``` related being used with this libraries no?

Comment: Inline scripts can't be used either. Use a separate js file: [onclick or inline script isn't working in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)

Comment: Ok @wOxxOm so that worked with the first option. So now I am trying again with "SortableJS" library to get the code locally and via file with no inline code. I am getting this: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined``` but actually ```Sortable``` is defined in the ```SortableJS.js``` file. I don't understand. Chrome won't recognize this function even if I open the file HTML directly via Browser and not via extension.

Comment: Solved it I guess. Added ```window.addEventListener("load", function () {  ``` and I also added the ```<script src="``` just before ```</body>``` Thank you!!